# Custom bookmarks that specificy the preferred OWA account

Tags: office-365, outlook-on-the-web, bookmarks

Is there a way to access Outlook on the Web from a bookmark that also specifies the specific account?

For example, I have two businesses that each have a Microsoft 365 account.

For example,

- info@businessONE.com
- info@businessTWO.com

However, I can't find a way to create individual bookmarks that link to their specific Outlook on the Web mailboxes.

In Gmail something similar can be achieved like this:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=your_email_goes_here
```

For example,

- https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=BusinessONE@gmail.com
- https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=BusinessTWO@gmail.com

Is there a similar approach for Outlook on the Web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer online but I found it in the page source code.

The URL parameters for logging into an Office Inbox:

```
https://outlook.office.com/mail/?actSwt=true&login_hint=your_email_goes_here
```

For example:

- https://outlook.office.com/mail/?actSwt=true&login_hint=info@businessONE.com
- https://outlook.office.com/mail/?actSwt=true&login_hint=info@businessTWO.com